# End tag a violates nesting rules

Tags: html, validation

I validated my code on W3 but this error comes up and I don't know how to fix it. here's my code

```
<section class="flex">
    <a href="mug.html">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="images/img5mug1.jpg" alt="We are Infinite mug">
        We are Infinite mug
    </a>
</section>
<section class="flex">
    <a href="tshirt.html">
        <div class="img">
        <img src="images/img6tshirt1.jpg" alt="The Perks of Being a Wallflower t-shirt">
        The Perks of Being a Wallflower t-shirt
    </a>
</section>
<section class="flex">
    <a href="bag.html"><div class="img">
        <img src="images/img7bag1.jpg"  alt="The Perks of Being a Wallflower bag">
        The Perks of Being a Wallflower tote bag
    </a>
</section>
<section class="flex">
    <a href="cap.html"><div class="img">
        <img src="images/img8cap1.jpg" alt="The Perks of Being a Wallflower cap">
        The Perks of Being a Wallflower cap
    </a>
</section>
```

Comment: what error? pasting that directly into the validator will fail as its expecting a full page...

Comment: `<div class="img">` - You don't seem to be closing this `<div>` anywhere...

Comment: You're not closing your `<div>` tags properly.

Comment: so did you read the error message? w3c validator tells you how to fix all of the errors.

Answer (score 3):

In each `a` you are opening but not closing a `div` with class 'img'. This probably isn't helping.

Plus, what doctype are you using? HTML 4.01 won't like you wrapping a `div` with an `a`, whereas HTML5 should be ok with it (although I assume you are using HTML5 since your snippet contains `section`).